# Win Error 2 below is entire message recieved when using Sublime Text on Windows 8 with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\python_work]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\]
[Finished]
```

Comment: The binary `python3.exe` no longer comes with Python for Windows, it's just `python.exe`. Edit your build system's `"cmd"` section to call `python` instead of `python3` and it should work.

Comment: The standard distribution of Python has never included "python3.exe". (Maybe it's included with an alternate distribution such as Anaconda.) To ensure that Python 3 is executed, use `py -3` instead of `python`.

Comment: @ErykSun really? I seem to recall `python3.exe` being in there at some point. Maybe it was just because I renamed the binary myself...

Comment: @MattDMo, if Python is installed locally in a filesystem that supports symlinks (e.g. the system drive) and you have the right to create symlinks (the right can be granted to any user or group), then it's best to use relative symlinks for the alternate names if you're creating them manually. Symlinks work fine as long as they're relative links in the same directory, and they'll continue to work after an in-place upgrade. For example, with 3.8 one would create "python3.exe" -> "python.exe" and "python3.8.exe" -> "python.exe".

Comment: @ErykSun right, that's what I do on *nix systems. On windows I just leave it be now, exactly because of the issue with in-place upgrades and having to remake the binaries, since I'm still distrustful of symlinks on Windows. I just use `py` there.